# Screen Resolution is Reversed

Tags: user-interface, mapping, screen, pixel, screen-resolution

[1024x600 screen, 600x1024 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbX7P.png)

Shown above is the issue I am facing. I have a screen that is 7" Screen Landscape. It should be 1024x600 yet when I use evtest I find that its actually 600x1024 but landscape. I have no idea how I would map this out within Figma and get the coordinates for anything on the screen. Any ideas?

Prerequisites

I can't use evtest to get the button coordinates on each screen as I am trying to map out certain buttons and using evtest kills the subprocess on the system. I need to map out the true coordinates in a program, or on paper.

I can't import or load any modules or modify the system in any way.

I have attempted to use x/600*1024, y/1024*600 but that doesn't line up with what I am seeing on screen.